# How to match a node with over n relationships using neo4j's Cypher Query Language?

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher, relationship

A node of a Round in a game is connected to Answer nodes.

(:Round)<-[:IN_ROUND]-(:Answer)

It is expected every Round to have 5 or fewer Answers related to it, I suspect there exists nodes in my database that have more than that, how can I query this information? Return all :Round nodes that have over 5 <-[:IN_ROUND]- relationships?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [WITH clause](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/with/) to count the number of connected nodes and then filter on this count.

If you wish to specify incoming connections to Round

```
MATCH (rnd:Round)<-[:IN_ROUND]-(a)
WITH rnd, count(a) as incomingNodes
WHERE incomingNodes>5
RETRUN rnd
```

If you want to count both incoming and outgoing connections:

```
MATCH (rnd:Round)-[:IN_ROUND]-(a)
WITH rnd, count(a) as connectedNodes
WHERE connectedNodes>5
RETRUN rnd
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
MATCH (n:Round)<-[:IN_ROUND]-(:Answer)
WHERE size((n)<-[:IN_ROUND]-(:Answer)) > 5
RETURN distinct(n)
```

You can see it works on this sample data:

```
MERGE (a:Round{key: 1})
MERGE (b:Round{key: 2})
MERGE (c:Answer{key: 3})
MERGE (d:Answer{key: 4})
MERGE (e:Answer{key: 5})
MERGE (f:Answer{key: 6})
MERGE (g:Answer{key: 7})
MERGE (h:Answer{key: 8})
MERGE (i:Answer{key: 9})

MERGE (c)-[:IN_ROUND{key:1}]-(a)
MERGE (d)-[:IN_ROUND{key:1}]-(a)
MERGE (e)-[:IN_ROUND{key:1}]-(a)
MERGE (f)-[:IN_ROUND{key:1}]-(a)
MERGE (g)-[:IN_ROUND{key:1}]-(a)
MERGE (h)-[:IN_ROUND{key:1}]-(a)
MERGE (i)-[:IN_ROUND{key:1}]-(b)
MERGE (c)-[:IN_ROUND{key:1}]-(b)
MERGE (e)-[:IN_ROUND{key:1}]-(b)
MERGE (f)-[:IN_ROUND{key:1}]-(b)
MERGE (g)-[:IN_ROUND{key:1}]-(b)
```

Returning:

```
╒═════════╕
│"n"      │
╞═════════╡
│{"key":1}│
└─────────┘
```